# how to remove a substring of characters from filenames in a directory?

Tags: rename

I know similar questions have been asked before but I couldn't find a thread that addresses the 'position' (1 to 5) to be replaced.
What is the best way to remove a number of characters from file names all stored in one directory?
e.g.:
from '0101 .jpg' to '.jpg',
from '0102 .jpg' to '.jpg',
from '0103 .jpg' to '.jpg' etc.

I would like to run this as batch.
Any help is much appreciated.
TIA

Comment: Eh these all end in .jpg. Not going to go very well as it will overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

To remove x characters from file names you can use `rename` (it id s perl command) with a regex:

```
rename -n 's/.{x}(.*)/$1/' *
```

where x can be replaced by 5 to remove the 1st 5 chars.

- The -n is for simulating; remove it to get the actual result.
- `sudo apt install rename` to install it.
- Example:

  ```
  $ touch 123456.txt 222222.txt 333333.txt
  $ rename -n 's/.{5}(.*)/$1/' *
  rename(123456.txt, 6.txt)
  rename(222222.txt, 2.txt)
  rename(333333.txt, 3.txt)
  ```
- If you want to add something at the front:

  ```
  rename -n 's/.{5}(.*)/3333$1/' *
  rename(123456.txt, 33336.txt)
  rename(222222.txt, 33332.txt)
  rename(333333.txt, 33333.txt)
  ```

Comment: There are at least two different `rename` programs out there and they are not completely compatible. There is a perl version and an executable coming from `util-linux`.

Comment: yeah that one is `rename.ul` The `rename` one is my "go to" one. It has the most examples online. There is also a GUI called rename that is very good.

Comment: worked like a charm. Thanks folks